# IO redirection with mkpipe for logging purposes

Tags: bash, logging, named-pipe

I have a bunch of scripts that send output to stdout. I am redirecting the output to files, but these files get large very very quickly. For example:

```
./script_with_lots_of_outpu.sh 2>&1 mylog.txt &
```

I would like to send the output to a named pipe instead so something like the following script could switch the file being written to:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
echo "USAGE: ./redir.sh pipename filename" 
fi

pipename=$1
filename=$2
trap filename="`date +%s`$filename" 2
mkfifo $pipename

while [ 1 -eq 1 ]
do
    read input
    echo $input >> $filename
done < $pipename
```

One could send this script a CTRL-C (or some other signal) and it would effectively cause the output of the pipe to start writing to a different file (prepended with a timestamp).

When I run this script and then echo something to it, it starts writing a ton of empty lines:

```
   > ./redir.sh testpipe testfile &
   > echo "this is a tesT" > testpipe
   > wc -l testfile
   627915 testfile
```

How can I make redir.sh only write out to a file when the pipe it reads from is written to?

EDIT

final product seems to be working as follows. I need to test some more to find out if it is production-worthy

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
    echo "USAGE: ./redir.sh pipename filename" 
    exit -1
fi

pipename=$1; rm $pipename;
origname=$2.log
filename=$2

rename()
{
    filename="$origname-`date +%s`"
    mv $origname $filename
    nohup nice -n 20 tar -czvf $filename.tar.gz $filename &
    trap rename 2
}

mkfifo $pipename
trap rename 2

while [ 1 -eq 1 ]
do
    read input
    echo $input >> $origname
done <> $pipename
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a caveat concerning the reading from a named pipe. When you open a named pipe your `open()` call hangs until a writer shows up. When a writer shows up subsequent `read()` calls will return whatever data the writer has written to the pipe. However, when the writer closes the pipe (or exits) the `read()` calls start returning 0 (rather than blocking).

This is the reason that instead of

```
int fd = open("testpipe", O_RDONLY);
```

one might want to open a pipe like this

```
int fd = open("testpipe", O_RDWR);
```

This way the process is not only the reader, but also the writer. Even though you never actually write anything to the pipe, this ensures that a writer *exists* and hence `read()` calls do not return 0, but block instead waiting for some writer to write something to the pipe.

Now, when your script does this:

```
while [ 1 -eq 1 ]
do
    read input
    ...
done < $pipename
```

your shell opens the pipe for reading only (`O_RDONLY`).

The solution to your problem is to make shell open the pipe for both reading and writing like this:

```
while [ 1 -eq 1 ]
do
    read input
    ...
done <> $pipename
```

Note the replacement of `< $pipename` with `<> $pipename`. This is what makes the shell open the pipe for both reading and writing (`O_RDWR`).

Comment: incredibly sorry for taking so long on responding. you suggestion worked beautifully.